# Finding 2 hop neighbourhood in neo4j excluding some specific relation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to find neighbour nodes of specific node. In my case I will extend it up to 2 hops . here is my situation

[image]

Here my first query for  hop detection was

```
Match (c:A{ID:'123'})-[*1..2]->(d)
Return Distinct(d)
```

which is now showing here. My data size is very huge nearly 8 million nodes. so for computational performance  I want to  remove  "DRIVE" and "Charges" where some charges  relationship are  self referenced

After some research I have got these

```
  Match (c:A{ID:'123'})-[r*1..2]->(d)
    where none(x in r WHERE type(x) in ['DRIVES', 'CHARGES'])
    Return Distinct(d)


Match (c:A{ID:'123'})-[:OWNS|:EARN_MONEY*1..2]->(d)
Return Distinct(d)
```

both query return same result but last one finish a bit early. The problem is I can't remove  self referenced charge  relation by this code and one or two drive relation is still there .Do I need to add something here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add an additional constraint to your query. Self edges have identical start and end points, so that's an easy way to identify them:

```
MATCH (c:A{ID:'123'})-[r:OWNS|:EARN_MONEY*1..2]->(d)
WHERE NONE(rel in r WHERE startNode(rel) = endNode(rel))
RETURN Distinct(d)
```

Comment: umm sorry it is giving the same result. self referenced loop is still there